# Using Regex to add quotations to delimited list

Tags: python, regex

I have a copied list I want to convert to a pandas data frame. However, when I copy the test I get raw values instead of strings. i.e
`foo, bar, buzz` instead of `" foo", "bar", "buzz"` the list then ends with numbers that I do not want to surround with quotations. I was able to select the text between 2 commas including a comma using `,[^,]+` but I do not want to include the comma because I want to replace the text inside with its quotation wrapped version. I cannot simply exclude numbers from the regex i.e `,[^,0-9]+` because some of the categories have numbers embedded in them (such as iPhone-6s or Toyota Rav4). How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Please share a proper example of your input data. Where does this list come from? It isn't entirely clear to me what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your CSV input be in a single string, you may try:

```
inp = "foo, bar, buzz, make-model"
output = re.sub(r'\b([\w-]+)\b', '"\\1"', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
"foo", "bar", "buzz", "make-model"
```

Comment: This is very close to correct for me! the problem is hyphenated entries get split. ,```"make"-"model"```, should be ```" make-model"```. Additionally, could you explain a bit more about how your query works?

Comment: @JoshZwiebel I patched my answer to cover hyphenated words.  There is not much to explain.  We capture any "word" (including two words connected by a hyphen), and then replace with that word enclosed in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ast.liter_eval()` like so:

```
import ast

my_string = "[1, 2, 'some_string', {'some':'dict'}]"
my_list = ast.literal_eval(my_string)
```

`my_list` then becomes:

```
[1, 2, 'some_string', {'some': 'dict'}]
```